# How to set a variable into a loop in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

According to this answer [Call a stored procedure for each row returned by a query in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326775/call-a-stored-procedure-for-each-row-returned-by-a-query-in-mysql) described as following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE foo() BEGIN
  DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE _id BIGINT UNSIGNED;
  DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM objects WHERE ...;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done := TRUE;

  OPEN cur;

  testLoop: LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO _id;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE testLoop;
    END IF;
    CALL testProc(_id);
  END LOOP testLoop;

  CLOSE cur;
END
```

How can i set a variable and increment it over each iteration?
The following code does't work and I don't know why.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE foo() BEGIN
      DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
      DECLARE _id BIGINT UNSIGNED;
      DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 0;
      DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM objects WHERE ...;
      DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done := TRUE;

      OPEN cur;

      testLoop: LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO _id;
        IF done THEN
          LEAVE testLoop;
        END IF;
        CALL testProc(_id);

        counter = counter + 1;

      END LOOP testLoop;

      CLOSE cur;
    END
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return value from MySQL stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362722/return-value-from-mysql-stored-procedure)

Comment: Try `set count = counter + 1` in the loop.