# Returning something from a stored procedure in MySql on success

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

i'm making a school project, i have to build a bank and do transfers etc.
so i've made two stored procedures, withdraw and deposit, both takes the account number and an amount as parameters.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`bank`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `withdraw`(
    IN p_account INT(11),
    IN p_amount DOUBLE
)
BEGIN

DECLARE p_balance double;
SELECT balance
INTO p_balance FROM
Accounts
WHERE
account_id = p_account;

IF p_balance >= p_amount THEN
UPDATE Accounts
SET balance = p_balance - p_amount
WHERE account_id = p_account;
//tell my php somehow
ELSE
//tell my php somehow
END IF;

END
```

i've been searching google dry, and i've tried:

to make a function and return a value from the function (some tutorial.. didnt work ofc xD)

to declare an output value (OUT p_result INT) and set the int, no luck

i've tried, to get that output value to work and im clueless.

what i want is in my php script

```
$sql = "CALL withdraw(1,500);"
$result = conn->query($sql);
if($result=true){
    conn->query("CALL deposit(2,500)");
} else {
    //inform user
}
```

EDIT!: i now SELECT something in my procedures, in deposit() the return is an email address.

In withdraw() the return is the account that has been withdrawed.
Both works fine 1 by 1.
but when i do withdraw() first, and then deposit() if withdraw succeeded, then it my var_dump($result) = bool(false)

Comment: you have to have `OUT`'s as well as `IN`'s

Comment: Yeah those 9 words doesn't really help alot. thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return value from MySQL stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362722/return-value-from-mysql-stored-procedure)

Comment: it states in your link, that the last thing selected by a stored procedure, is available to the calling environment, which would be my PHP script. my deposit(1,1) stored procedure is working in mysql workbench, and it selects the email of the receiver. thus its still returning bool(false) (from var_dump)

Answer (score 0):

Stored PROCEDURES can return a resultset. The last thing you SELECT in a stored procedure is available as a resultset to the calling environment.. Stored FUNCTIONS can return only a single result primitive.